# Radius of convergence in p-adics

Tags: number-theory, power-series, p-adic-number-theory

Let $f(x)=\displaystyle{\sum_n a_nx^n}$ be a power series with coefficients in the field of p-adic rationals, $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $R_f$ be its radius of convergence and let $f'$ denote its term-by-term derivative.

I have two (related) questions:

$(1)$ Is it the case that $R_f\leq R_{f'}$?

$(2)$ Is it ever possible that the inequality is strict?

We have that
$$\frac{1}{R_{f}}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|_p^{1/n}$$
and
$$\frac{1}{R_{f'}}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}|na_n|_p^{1/n}$$
by the so-called root test.

Now, $$|na_n|_p^{1/n}=|n|_p^{1/n}|a_n|_p^{1/n}$$
I want to somehow show that the $|n|_p^{1/n}$ forces the limit superior to be larger than that of the original function, but am stuck.

As for the second question, my inuition tells me that this should  be possible? I'm having trouble ocming up with a solid (counter)example.

Thanks!

Edit: Fixed the multiple typos in the radius of convergence formula.

Comment: I believe also your formula for $1/R_{f'}$ is slightly off since the $n$th coefficient of $f'$ is $(n+1)a_{n+1}$, thus you want $\limsup |(n+1)a_{n+1}|_p^{1/n} \leq \limsup |a_{n}|_p^{1/n}$. After you note that $|n+1|_p \leq 1$, you'll need to prove the fact that $\limsup b_n^{1/n} = \limsup b_n^{1/(n+1)}$ or something like this.

Answer (score 3):

The root test is the replacement of $\varlimsup$ by the more restrictive $\lim$. Not all sequences have a limit, but they all have a $\varlimsup$ in the extended real numbers.

**Example**.  The sequence $\sqrt[n]{|n|_p}$ has no limit, but it has a $\varlimsup$. Can you compute it?

**Remark**. The series $f(x) = \sum_{k \geq 0} x^{p^k}$ converges if and only if $|x|_p < 1$, while $f'(x) = \sum_{k \geq 0} p^kx^{p^k-1}$ converges if $|x|_p \leq 1$, so $f'$ converges on a *larger* set than $f$. This is quite unlike the situation in $\mathbf C$: the complex power series $\sum_{n \geq 1} x^n/n^2$ converges if and only if $|x| \leq 1$, but the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} x^{n-1}/n$ does not converge at $x = 1$: the derivative converges on a *smaller* set than the original series.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot the superior when I was typing the question. I'm still not seeing how this correction helps to solve the problem, however.

Comment: You're still using the *wrong* formula even if you use $\varlimsup$.  I already pointed out that your formula is incorrect for $\sum p^nx^n$.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for the very helpful remark. I kept trying things involving factorials and not making any progress. Can I ask what the thought process behind coming up with an example that worked would be?

Comment: What do you mean by "an example that worked"?

Comment: The example $\sum x^{p^k}$

Comment: The thought process is just experience.  When learning this stuff, I remembered such things from books that I had read.

Comment: One last question: I thought that open and closed balls were the same in the p-adic (ultra)metric topology. Wouldn't that mean that $|x|_p<1$ was the same was $|x|_p\leq 1$? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: And are you aware that over $\mathbf R$ and $\mathbf C$ the radii of convergence of $f$ and $f'$ are equal? This is discussed in lots of places online and in analysis books. Understand such proofs and then see how they can be adapted to the $p$-adic setting.

Comment: Certainly $|x|_p < 1$ is not at all the same thing as $|x|_p = 1$: all of $\mathbf Z_p^\times$ (like $x = \pm 1$) fits the second condition but not the first. In the $p$-adics, the *definition* of an open ball is a closed set and the *definition* of a closed ball is an open set (for positive radius), but that does not mean the definitions of open and closed balls of the same radius are the same sets: you have to pay attention to what you're actually talking about. Do you think a closed ball in a metric space is never an open set or an open ball in a metric space is never a closed set?

Comment: When we use the terms "open ball" and "closed ball" we mean the concepts going by those names from a general metric space (with bounds $< r$ and $\leq r$, respectively). But if an open ball is a closed *set* or a closed ball is an open *set* (using the definitions of open and closed sets in metric spaces), that does not make an open ball of radius $r$ the same as a closed ball of radius $r$ or a closed ball of radius $r$ the same as an open ball of radius $r$. Don't mix up the terms open ball and open set or the terms closed ball and closed set.

Comment: On the other hand, in $\mathbf Q_p$ we can say $|x|_p < 1$ is the same as $|x|_p \leq 1/p$ and $|x|_p \leq 1$ is the same as $|x|_p < p$. The reasoning behind that is why in $\mathbf Q_p$ the open balls are closed balls and the closed balls are open balls, but *not* with the same radii.